How to apply Gimp3 layer mask with Gegl 0.4? (or: How to use gegl:opacity?)
Problem
Use Gegl to apply a layermask in Gimp2.99



Gimp project structure
desired result









UPDATE
This is an aproximation towards the result I would like to get, but the problem is not solved, yet. I still need to be able to apply a layer mask in Gimp using Gegl, creating the exact same result the Gimp users sees in the preview, or gets when manually exporting from Gimp.

One way, I found, to apply the transparency information of the mask to its layer is as follows.
Convert the masks black to alpha (gegl:color-to-alpha), extract the alpha component (gegl:extract-component), multiply with the foreground (gegl:multiply) and then lay over the background (gegl:over).
If you put a gegl:invert node before and after the gegl:color-to-alpha and let it convert white to alpha, the result is quite different:



approach
result




black-to-alpha  (to little)



invert white-to-alpha invert  (to much)



desired result  (Gimp export)




So the truth lies in the middle.
The Gegl graph
arrows:
⏺ = "input", x = "aux"

The Code
# get image
img = Gimp.list_images()[0]

# get Gimp objects
l_foreground = img.get_layer_by_name("foreground")
l_background = img.get_layer_by_name("background")
mask = l_foreground.get_mask()

# Gegl graph root
graph = Gegl.Node()

# foreground
fg_node = graph.create_child("gegl:buffer-source")
fg_node.set_property("buffer", l_foreground.get_buffer())

# mask
mask_node = graph.create_child("gegl:buffer-source")
mask_node.set_property("buffer", mask.get_buffer())

# background
bg_node = graph.create_child("gegl:buffer-source")
bg_node.set_property("buffer", l_background.get_buffer())

# convert color black to alpha
cta_node = graph.create_child("gegl:color-to-alpha")
color = Gegl.Color()
color.set_rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)
cta_node.set_property("color", color)

# extract alpha
ea_node = graph.create_child("gegl:extract-component")
ea_node.set_property("component", "Alpha")

# apply extracted alpha to foreground
apply_alpha_node = graph.create_child("gegl:multiply")

# lay (processed) foreground over background
compose_node = graph.create_child("gegl:over")

# export .png file
sink_node = graph.create_child("gegl:png-save")
sink_node.set_property("bitdepth", 16)
sink_node.set_property("path", "/path/to/result.png")

# connect the nodes
mask_node.link(cta_node)
cta_node.link(ea_node)

# toggle comment to get the second result described above
# color.set_rgba(1, 1, 1, 1)
# inv1 = graph.create_child("gegl:invert")
# inv2 = graph.create_child("gegl:invert")
# mask_node.link(inv1)
# inv1.link(cta_node)
# cta_node.link(inv2)
# inv2.link(ea_node)

ea_node.link(apply_alpha_node)
fg_node.connect("output", apply_alpha_node, "aux")
bg_node.link(compose_node)
apply_alpha_node.connect("output", compose_node, "aux")
compose_node.link(sink_node)

# process
sink_node.process()


ORIGINAL QUESTION
My approach to applying the mask is to convert its black to alpha (gegl:color-to-alpha operation), and then apply this information to the actual layer (gegl:opacity operation). But the gegl:opacity operation seems to somehow round the alpha values? So instead of a nice, soft transition, the result is a sharp edge, as illustrated below.



Gimp project structure
desired result













actual output
after gegl:color-to-alpha
after gegl:opacity




black to alpha





white to alpha(easier to seewhat's happening)






My Gegl graph
o = output   i = input   a = aux


| buffer-source |
|               o -----------------------------------+
|    fg_node    |                                    |
                                                     |
                                                     |
                                                     i
| buffer-source |      | color-to-alpha |      |  opacity   |
|               o ---- i                o ---- a            |
|   mask_node   |      |    cta_node    |      | blend_node |
                                                     o
                                                     |
                                                     |
| buffer-source |                |     over     |    |
|               o -------------- i              a ---+
|    bg_node    |                | compose_node |
                                         o
                                         |
                   | png-save  |         |
                   |           i --------+
                   | sink_node |

My code so far
# get image
img = Gimp.list_images()[0]

# get Gimp objects
l_foreground = img.get_layer_by_name("foreground")
l_background = img.get_layer_by_name("background")
mask = l_foreground.get_mask()

# Gegl graph root
graph = Gegl.Node()

# foreground
fg_node = graph.create_child("gegl:buffer-source")
fg_node.set_property("buffer", l_foreground.get_buffer())

# mask
mask_buffer = mask.get_buffer()
mask_node = graph.create_child("gegl:buffer-source")
mask_node.set_property("buffer", mask_buffer)

# background
bg_node = graph.create_child("gegl:buffer-source")
bg_node.set_property("buffer", l_background.get_buffer())

# convert color black to alpha 
cta_node = graph.create_child("gegl:color-to-alpha")

# apply opacity of aux to input?
blend_node = graph.create_child("gegl:opacity")

# lay (processed) foreground over background
compose_node = graph.create_child("gegl:over")

# export .png file
sink_node = graph.create_child("gegl:png-save")
sink_node.set_property("bitdepth", 8)
sink_node.set_property("path", "/path/to/result.png")

# connect the nodes
compose_node.link(sink_node)
blend_node.connect("output", compose_node, "aux")
cta_node.connect("output", blend_node, "aux")
mask_node.link(cta_node)
fg_node.link(blend_node)
bg_node.link(compose_node)

# process
sink_node.process()

I also tried to use the gegl:extract-component operation with property component = "Alpha", but it produces the same result as gegl:opacity.
I'm completely new to image processing and Gegl, and don't know a lot about the inner workings of things, yet. Am I even taking the right approach, or is the opacity operation not meant to do what I hope it does?
